# How to troubleshoot cudaErrorUnknown from cudaDeviceSynchronize()?

Tags: c++, cuda

I have a large code base that performs RGB to YUV color conversion with CUDA kernels. Since I am doing a lot of parallel conversions, I use streams (maybe that is relevant here). The code is running on Linux, It is working fine on a Quadro K4200 GPU but I recently got a new Quadro P4000 GPU on which I constantly get `cudaErrorUnknown` when calling `cudaDeviceSynchronize()`. Before this happens the only things I do are a call to `cuMemcpy2DAsync` to copy the pixel data and after that a call to my kernel. The code base is large and I can share some relevant parts, but can anyone give advice how could I troubleshoot this? Since I was working with the K4200 all the time, I haven't changed the CUDA compiler flags. Should I do that? I am currently compiling the same code for both cards with the following flags:

```
--compiler-bindir /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 -gencode=arch=compute_30,code=\"sm_30,compute_30\" -cudart static -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -g -G -std=c++11 -D_MWAITXINTRIN_H_INCLUDED
```

But in that case is it even possible to make a single object that runs on different GPUs?

This is the output of `nvidia-smi`:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 384.90                 Driver Version: 384.90                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro P4000        Off  | 00000000:04:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 46%   39C    P0    29W / 105W |      0MiB /  8112MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Quadro K4200        Off  | 00000000:84:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 30%   40C    P0    26W / 110W |      0MiB /  4036MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Should I disable the old card, could the driver seeing both cards start to behave incorrectly? Are there any internal NVIDIA logs/tools that I can use to get a more detailed description of what is failing?

Comment: Have you tried running in `cuda-memcheck` or `cuda-gdb` already?

Comment: Yes, you should change your build command. Add `-gencode=arch=compute61,code=sm_61` to build for your device.

Comment: @tera, yep that fixed it and now the old card throws `cudaErrorNoKernelImageForDevice`. What is the general approach to solve the issue of running the same kenrel on cards with different architectures? Generating multiple objects from same cpp, prefixing function names and then bundling all that together?

Answer (score 1):

> How to troubleshoot ... ?

By transforming your program into a

[Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

of this issue manifesting.

This will focus your "list of suspects" to very few CUDA API calls, which should either be enough for you to figure out the problem by yourself or would make it possible for you to post the whole thing (in a different question) here and get proper help. Or you'll find out the problem goes away as you drop supposedly-irrelevant parts of the code, meaning that it lies with what you've just removed.

Comment: I understand this very well, the issue is that even though I have made a smaller example, the same code works fine for one device and fails on the other, so the intention of the question was to understand if there are internal NVIDIA tools I could use since  `cudaErrorUnknown` doesn't give much to work with. The question was not inteded as a "how can I debug stuff" question, more of a "hey, guys who work with CUDA daily, maybe you have some tips" question.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis: Can't you post that code which works on one device and fails on the other?

Comment: the suggestion to switch the arch already fixed the issue, so basically I got what I wanted:)

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis: Then please consider explaining what you did in an answer, and expanding as much as you're able to regarding what the exact issue was. Remember that the primary audience of these answers is not you, but the dozens/hundreds/thousands of other people (when they're all put together) who will read this Q&A page later on.

Answer (score 1):

Recompiling the kernel with the correct architecture flags `-gencode=arch=compute_61,code=sm_61` as suggested by @tera fixed it for Quadro P4000, however now the same code fails on Quadro K4200, but this time with a reasonable error `cudaErrorNoKernelImageForDevice`:

> This indicates that there is no kernel image available that is suitable for the device. This can occur when a user specifies code generation options for a particular CUDA source file that do not include the corresponding device configuration.

So apparently my biggest problem was the lack of knowledge to understand what could be causing the `cudaErrorUnknown`.

Comment: You can have multiple `-gencode` arguments in the same build command, one for each architecture you want to support.

Comment: @tera - thanks, I did not know this:) I was already starting to make a makefile that would make multiple objects out of the source file and mangle the function names. Thank you very much.